# Combined atmospheric data visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib

Are there any Python solutions out in the web for satellite/radar/lidar/aircraft based 2D/3D visualization of atmospheric measurements. My interest range vary from simply overlaying flight tracks over satellite images/data to co-located visualizations of lidar/radar/aircraft measurements (within themselves) and with matching satellite pixels.

I would be happy to know if such visualization attempts (tools or custom Python scripts) exist before I start working on my own solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: Another visualization example in addition to the composites from NASA's field campaign, the figures (listed in the last 4 pages) in this draft paper http://www-das.uwyo.edu/~vali/dycoms/poc_30920.pdf

I would like to make some information and code exchange with someone experienced creating similar visuals.

Comment: What are each of the data formats? Could they be combined with imshow and pcolormesh?

Comment: Possibly 2D plotting functions within mpl is the right approach to take as you suggested. Data are in netcdf4 and hdf5 containers.

Answer (score 2):

For the 2D images you might want to consider the use of [NCL](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/), produced by NCAR (The National Center for Atmospheric Research), which is specifically designed for manipulating and plotting atmospheric (meteorological) data. An impressive gallery of results is available on that [site](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/gallery.shtml). IMO NCL's syntax can be very ugly at times, and it looks as if a python wrapper, [PyNGL](http://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/) now exists ([gallery](http://www.pyngl.ucar.edu/Examples/gallery.shtml))

For visualization of 3D atmospheric data, some of my colleagues have used a number of very impressive tools including [vis5d](http://vis5d.sourceforge.net/) and [vapour](http://www.vapor.ucar.edu/).

For the ultimate in flexibility, [mayavi2](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/), which is basically a MATLAB style ipython interface to Kitware's [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) library is used in a huge range of scientific visualizations. I don't recommend this approach unless you're happy to 'roll your own', but it is a very nice if you need to get a three dimensional results looking just right.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a rather vague.  Are the 2D/3D visualizations images that you have or are you rendering them yourself?  Are they contour plots or arrays of data?  There is a wide variety of python packages, but without being more specific I would suggest looking into [this website](http://en.literateprograms.org/Drawing_on_map_projections_%28Python%29).  I've used

```
matplotlib.backends.backendbackend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
```

for some of my data and I've heard good things about Basemap.  It all depends on what you what to do with what you've got.

Comment: At the very basic level, I am interested in creating plots similar to those shown at: http://geo.arc.nasa.gov/sgg/INTEX-B/MODISrgb_images/MODISrgb_images.html
I am starting with the data containers (either in netcdf4 or hdf5) then working on creating the visuals. Although I am aware with the basemap, I haven't seen any example so far demonstrating to plot MODIS granules.

Comment: If you are using hdf5, I would suggest getting the ATPY package to read in your data - it's pretty useful.  Also, it would seem that some answers may be [here](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/wordpress/?p=86), [here](http://groups.google.com/group/python-gis-sig/browse_thread/thread/731f681c7b89dbed), or [here](http://old.nabble.com/Plotting-MODIS-data-in-Python---basemap---a-MODIS-workflow-solution--td26075361.html) - the overall conclusion being to use GDAL.

Comment: Thanks cosmosis. matplotlib+basemap duo is the solution as I initially expected. However GDAL seems to be one extra abstract layer which I don't want to include much in my case.

Answer (score 1):

One-self answer:

[ccplot](http://ccplot.org/)

> ***ccplot is an open source command-line application that is capable of producing two-dimensinal plots of profile, layer and earth view data sets from CloudSat CPR, CALIPSO CALIOP, and Aqua MODIS HDF4 and HDF-EOS2 files.***

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this question now with similar needs there is a tool called [CIS](http://cistools.net) which provides plotting and collocation of a range of datasets including aircraft data, CALIOP L2, MODIS L2 and others. It also provides subsetting and aggregation of the data, in case that's of use.

It's a command line tool primarily but there's a Python API too - see http://cis.readthedocs.org for more info.

Full disclosure: I'm the lead dev on this tool, and I'm happy to give more specific answers to more specific questions.

Comment: Do you have any connection to this project? If so, please be sure to [disclose your affiliation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).